# Adding two datarows into a third row

Tags: c#, data-binding, datarow

Is it possible to add two datarows and get the result in the third datarow of the same datatable in c#?
Also, is it possible to bind the two datarows to the result row so that if any values change, it is reflected in the resultant row?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont fully understand your question.
Do you want to show the result of 2 rows (like for each colom the sum of numbers) in a 3rd row?

Comment: yes. the third row should contain the sum of the above two row values in the respective columns. I want to know if there is a way to do it without using the individual row and column indices.

Comment: Also, can we do databinding in a datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Edited response for use with [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), again I haven't tested this code just wrote it up.

```
    public static class DataTableHandler
    {
        private const string COL_PRICE = "PriceColumn";
        private const string COL_QUANTITY = "QuantityColumn";

        public static DataTable AddTotalRow(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            int totalQuantity = 0;
            decimal totalPrice = 0.0;

            CalculateTotals(dataTable, out totalQuantity, out totalPrice);

            DataRow row = dataTable.AddRow();
            row.Cells[COL_QUANTITY].Value = totalQuantity;
            row.Cells[COL_PRICE].Value = totalPrice;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            return dataTable;
        }

        private static void CalculateTotals(DataTable dataTable, out int totalQuantity, out decimal totalPrice)
        {
            totalPrice = 0.0;
            totalQuantity = 0;

            foreach (DataRow r in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                totalPrice += (decimal)r.Cells[COL_PRICE].Value;
                totalQuantity += (int)r.Cells[COL_QUANTITY].Value;
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I am building is a tool with a datatable as the output so that it can be bound to any type of UI. So I want to do the binding in the datatable itself. Is it possible?

Comment: Ah, yes it's possible to add rows to a datatable / dataset. Will add a code block for it in an edit.

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear. What I want is adding two datarows i.e. if 'A' is a data row and 'B' is another data row, is it possible to get C=A+B, where 'C' is also a data row that already exists in the table. And 'A' and 'B' are not the only rows in the table. There are many rows and 'A' and 'B' are two selected rows whose indices are known. For 'C' too only the index is known. I want to add the values of 'A' and 'B' into 'C' (for the corresponding columns). All datarows of the same table so has the same schema. Also I don't know the column names, just the indices.

Comment: Ah, okay. I think I got it now, you want the "bottom"-row to show the sum of two (or more?) selected rows? If that's what you want it's totallty doable. Will look at it a bit later, at work right now.